# compute ci square distance in python

Tags: image-processing, vectorization, knn, chi-squared

im using knn model from sklean (- documentation
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) to train some model for images classification. as you can see in the documentation, there is no option to pass the chi square distance as a metric to the KNeighborsClassifier function. but there is an option to pass a callable item-so i can pass a function that i built to calc the chi square. so i tried to write my own function.
i know that for some two images, the chi square is calculated up to this formula:
[formula to calaculate chi square distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xONlQ.png)

my task is to solve this problem without using for loops as it takes too long. i need to solve this using vectorization, as my data passed to the chi square are images so if i have two images represented as np arrays' i can do math actions on them without loops, i mean for example for A=[1,2,3] and B=[3,4,5], A+B just give us [4,6,8], no need to use loop to calc this. i this way i also need to calc the chi square function.

anyway, when i tried for example this function:

```
def chi2(A, B):
#compute the chi-squared distance using above formula

chi = 0.5 * (((A - B) ** 2) / (A + B))


return chi
```

to calc the chi square, i get an error, and if i try some others similar functions, for example this code :

```
def chi2(A, B):
#compute the chi-squared distance using above formula

def chi2_distance(A, B):
    # compute the chi-squared distance using above formula
    chi = 0.5 * np.sum([((a - b) ** 2) / (a + b)
                        for (a, b) in zip(A, B)])

    return chi
```

i get warnings: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
for (a, b) in zip(A, B)])

and the program running like forever.

any suggestions to some efficient code to calc the chi square distance (as i said, with no loops)?

Comment: What's wrong with just using the scikit-learn pairwise chi-squared kernel function ? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.additive_chi2_kernel.html

Comment: actually, i already tried this method, but that gives me some very low score for the model. i mean, using for example euclidean built in distance gave me like 0.76 accuracy score and when i tried that function  it gave me like 0.03 or something like that. isnt that  strange? i guessed that it wont work well, also i wondered if the formula in there (k(x, y) = -Sum [(x - y)^2 / (x + y)]
)  represent the same formula i gave? what is that minus sign for

Comment: That second implementation looks just like the example at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chi-square-distance-in-python/ Do you get the same result for their test cases?

Comment: yes, i took it from there. credit to geeksforgeeks btw. anyway, i didnt tried their test cases as it is the same function so it should work. i dont know why the combination of the knnClassifier function with that function dont work - KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i,metric=chi2) , as i said it gave me that warning RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars for (a, b) in zip(A, B)])  ,and runs forever

Comment: Well you are getting a runtime warning with code based on that example, so trying their test cases would rule out, or detect a possible typo.I just ran their code exactly as shown in a Jupyter notebook, and it runs fine.

Comment: their test cases are for some basic,small arrays and numbers. im passing much bigger arrays that represent a pictures after doing on them hog function for features selection, if you are familiar with that and know what im talking about. my array includes numbers like:  [1.00763747e-01 3.23137453e-01 4.11395666e-01 1.19438552e-01
 3.28196456e-02 1.08636323e-03 1.83117069e-02 5.28662415e-03] maybe the problem is here?

Comment: Do you get their result with your adaptation of their code for their sample data, or do you not? This is what unit test is all about. Diagnose simple issues before determining if there is a more complex issue on a larger data set.